# RestKit Object Mapping Relationships without KVC

Tags: iphone, core-data, restkit, relationships

After reading the [Object Mapping-Guide on GitHub](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping) for RestKit my problem didn't disappear, so perhaps somebody can say if RestKit could deal with the following idea.

**Entities with Relationships**

```
 Company 
 - unitID 
 - companyID
 - name
 - contacts* (Company -->> Contact | 1:n)

 Contact
 - unitID
 - companyID
 - contactID
 - lastName
 - firstName
 - account* (Contact >--> Company | 1:1)
```

**JSON (Company)**

```
 [
   {
      "unitID":"003CABD8DEB5DC13C",
      "companyID":"BSP-002999",
      "name":"Testcompany"
   }
 ]
```

**JSON (Contact)**

```
 [
   {
      "unitID":"DAC2ACCC125795D00",
      "companyID":"BSP-002999",
      "contactID":"CLP-015468",
      "firstName":"Mister",
      "lastName":"Wayne"
   }
 ]
```

Due to limitations I'm not able to nest the belonging contacts into the companies (otherwise I wouldn't write this), so I want to do this use when the data is mapped on import.

## Question

Is it possible to map each Contact to it's belonging Company (identified by the attribute *companyID*) on import with given methods by RestKit?

*If not, I would like to know the best solution for it. Thanks!*

---

**Background**

In my first build of this app I've mapped the objects to the given entities (without relationships) and fetched all belonging contacts to a company with the predicate *companyID = %@*. Due to the amount of data (4000+ Companies, 7000+ Contacts) fetching all belonging contacts takes about a second  - so I came up with the idea to use relationsships (which works perfect with local dummy data).

---

## Solution

With the help of the given answer below my current mapping looks like the following (RestKit v.10).

```
// Setting up Restkit with objectStore
...

// Init objectMapping for Class Company
companyMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Company class] inManagedObjectStore:objectStore];
[companyMapping mapKeyPath:@"unitID" toAttribute:@"unitID"];
[companyMapping mapKeyPath:@"companyID" toAttribute:@"companyID"];
[companyMapping mapKeyPath:@"name" toAttribute:@"name"];
companyMapping.setDefaultValueForMissingAttributes = NO;
companyMapping.primaryKeyAttribute = @"companyID";

// Init objectMapping for Class Contact
contactMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Contact class] inManagedObjectStore:objectStore];
[contactMapping mapKeyPath:@"unitID" toAttribute:@"unitID"];
[contactMapping mapKeyPath:@"companyID" toAttribute:@"companyID"];
[contactMapping mapKeyPath:@"contactID" toAttribute:@"contactID"];
[contactMapping mapKeyPath:@"lastName" toAttribute:@"lastName"];
[contactMapping mapKeyPath:@"firstName" toAttribute:@"firstName"];
contactMapping.setDefaultValueForMissingAttributes = NO;
contactMapping.primaryKeyAttribute = @"contactID";

// Init relationships
[contactMapping mapRelationship:@"company" withMapping:companyMapping];
[contactMapping connectRelationship:@"company" withObjectForPrimaryKeyAttribute:@"companyID"];

// Get objects from server
...
```

Comment: Could you please share your working solution of this example? :) Just for the mappings

Comment: Updated my entry above with an example configuration. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, RestKit can hydrate this relationship for you at mapping time. On your RKManagedObjectMapping for your Contact model, you will need to do the following:

- Add a relationship mapping to the parent Company: `[objectMapping mapRelationship:@"company" withMapping:companyMapping]`
- Map the companyID attribute onto your Contact model
- Ensure that you have the primaryKeyAttribute configured on both classes
- Instruct RestKit to hydrate the relationship: `[objectMapping connectRelationship:@"company" withObjectForPrimaryKeyAttribute:@"companyID"];`

After RestKit has completed mapping a payload, it will pass back through the collection and hydrate any relationships. The processing is deferred until after mapping in case the payload actually creates objects that you need to satisfy the connections.

On the development branch, there is an alternative workflow available to you. Earlier this week I added support for hydrating a has-many relationship using an array of ID's in the payload. This would let you send the list of Contacts that belong to a company down in the payload instead. It may be more efficient for your use case.

Additional details from my post to the RestKit mailing list: http://groups.google.com/group/restkit/msg/416951f86b2862d1

Comment: Thanks for your fast replay - it works like a charm! I'm watching the projekt on GitHub/Google now, because you're second idea seems to be great for this project.

Comment: You saved my day! :) It seems like you need a foreign key in your entity that points to the parent entity you want to hydrate. Anyway, I went through all kinds of docs and examples but I just don't get how it works. This is the best explanation so far on how to finally get this thing to work!