# Correct way to map Core Data relationship

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I have two objects I need to create a relationship between in Core Data. I am not sure how to setup the relationship. When I try I then run my app it loops forever and crashes (guessing circular reference).

mainObject.h

```
NSString *userId;
NSString *thing;
NSString *descr;
NSString *title;
```

authObject.h

```
NSString *userId;
BOOL     alive;
BOOL     authCode;
```

How do I setup this relationship in CD? mainObject can have multiple authObjects. How do I relate userId on both objects to each other in CD?

Comment: What does your data model look like? Relationships are defined there, and the properties and ivars are generated automatically in your managed object subclass files.

Comment: mainObject has-many authObjects  (see above for their attributes). The relationship on mainObject side is "auths" and the relationship (inverse) on the authObjects is "main".

Comment: Something similar here, but I think I can figure it out from this post stackoverflow.com/questions/9318565/restkit-object-mapping-relationships-without-kvc/9318745#9318745

Comment: It's not clear where your problem is. Core data relationships are just properties on an object - for example, you'd set the `main` property on your authObject to an instance of `mainObject` and boom - you're done. Can you include some of the code you are trying that is causing you difficulties?

Comment: Answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318565/restkit-object-mapping-relationships-without‌​-kvc/9318745#9318745

Comment: Please answer your question with the solution you found and set it as marked. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure how that does answer your question, since it is about Restkit, which you haven't mentioned, but you know best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using restkit and my scenario is identical to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318565/restkit-object-mapping-relationships-without%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B-kvc/9318745#9318745)

As for the CoreData side, I figured it out by reading through that post and filling in the gaps. Mainly, I had it pretty much right, but that post confirmed my suspicions.

Not sure how to mark this as answered.

Comment: Just click the grey check box under the vote box to accept your own answer.