# Problems with RestKit Object Mapping in 0.10.1

Tags: objective-c, xcode, restkit

As a following question to the [solved issue with the object mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318565/restkit-object-mapping-relationships-without-kvc) I've upgraded RestKit to 0.10.1 and extended the data model to the following.

A **company** can have multiple contacts and activities, a **contact** can have multiple activities but only one company, an **activity** can only have one company and one contact.

**Entities with Relationships**

```
 Company 
 - unitID 
 - companyID
 - matchcode
 - contacts* (Company -->> Contact | 1:n)
 - activities* (Company -->> Activity | 1:n)

 Contact
 - unitID
 - companyID
 - contactID
 - lastName
 - firstName
 - company* (Contact >--> Company | 1:1)
 - activities* (Contact -->> Activity | 1:n)

 Activity
 - unitID
 - activityID
 - companyID
 - contactID
 - subject
 - account* (Activity >--> Company | 1:1)
 - contact* (Activity >--> Contact | 1:1)
```

**JSON (Company)**

```
 [
   {
      "unitID":"003CABD8DEB5DC13C",
      "companyID":"BSP-002999",
      "matchcode":"Testcompany"
   }
 ]
```

**JSON (Contact)**

```
 [
   {
      "unitID":"DAC2ACCC125795D00",
      "companyID":"BSP-002999",
      "contactID":"CLP-015468",
      "firstName":"Mister",
      "lastName":"Wayne"
   }
 ]
```

**JSON (Activity)**

```
 [
   {
      "unitID":"E123FlADAS2DASD2F",
      "activityID":"ACT-123912",
      "companyID":"BSP-002999",
      "contactID":"CLP-015468",
      "subject":"Testsubject",
   }
 ]
```

**Object Mapping - Setting up the connections**

```
 // Objects
 companyMapping.primaryKeyAttribute = @"companyID";
 ...
 contactMapping.primaryKeyAttribute = @"contactID";
 ...
 activityMapping.primaryKeyAttribute = @"activityID";

 // Connections
 [contactMapping mapRelationship:@"company" withMapping:companyMapping];
 [contactMapping connectRelationship:@"company" withObjectForPrimaryKeyAttribute:@"companyID"];

 [activityMapping mapRelationship:@"company" withMapping:companyMapping];
 [activityMapping connectRelationship:@"company" withObjectForPrimaryKeyAttribute:@"companyID"];

 [activityMapping mapRelationship:@"contact" withMapping:contactMapping];
 [activityMapping connectRelationship:@"contact" withObjectForPrimaryKeyAttribute:@"contactID"];
```

---

**Problem**

The first two mapping operations work like they should but somehow the last mapping **activity >--> contact** doesn't work.

[image: No connection for contact]

Thanks for any ideas to solve it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem on my own because there was an error in the configuration of Core Data.

The relationship **Contact -->> Activity** wasn't set to "optional" and Xcode and RestKit didn't show a clear error. Setting it to "optional" solved the problem and the mapping works for all relationships.